# Scons in Scratchbox: Can't find g++

Tags: environment-variables, scons, cross-compiling, scratchbox

I've been using sbox with a Make-based codebase with no problems. Now
I'm using a scons-based codebase, and am getting some odd problems.

It seems that within scratchbox, scons can't find g++. For example, it
attempts to execute things like:

o hello hello.c

When it should be doing:

g++ -o hello hello.c

So presumably its g++ string variable is empty. g++ is present and in
the PATH - "which g++" produces /scratchbox/compilers/bin/g++.

The same source builds fine outside of scratchbox, so it shouldn't be
a problem with scons or the codebase. There are no special environment
variables set outside of scratchbox when it works.

If I symbolically link /usr/bin/g++ to /scratchbox/compilers/bin/g++,
it gets a bit further (produces the correct-looking g++ commands) but
then upon executing them produces:

sb_gcc_wrapper (g++):
/scratchbox/compilers/arm-linux-cs2007q3-51sb3/bin/sbox-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++:
No such file or directory

The file listed *is* present.

PATH contains /scratchbox/compilers/bin, SBOX_REDIRECT_FROM_DIRS contains /usr/bin and SBOX_REDIRECT_TO_DIRS contains /scratchbox/compilers/bin, so I think it *should* be able to find it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Thanks,
Ray

Edit: Perhaps related - it also can't find pkg-config unless I prepend the full path within the scons file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

scons does not propagate the PATH environment variable, so testing e.g. 'which g++' doesn't help much.

```
Either set the compilers directly, e.g.
env['CXX'] = '/scratchbox/compilers/bin/g++'
```

Build your own explicit PATH

```
path = ['/scratchbox/compilers/bin/','/bin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin','/usr/sbin']
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

Or use the PATH env variable from your shell

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

Comment: Thanks - this has basically solved the problem. Importing PATH fixed the pkg-config and g++ location issues, but still had the file not found error for sbox-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++. I did the bad thing and imported the whole environment with "ENV = os.environ", and now g++ works ok...